# Java - Unable to obtain HTML plaintext from webside

Tags: java, html, https, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have a strange problem. I have in the past used a program I wrote myself to check if a new chapter has come out on a story at fanfiction.net and that program works fine even now (though its GUI leaves a lot to wish for).

However, when I am trying to make a new version I can't seem to load the webpage even though I'm using the exact same code (Copy Pasted). This is the code below. When sending in a URL like *https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11012678/36* to the nextExists method it should return 'true'. My old program does, but this one doesn't even though it's the same code.

The only thing I can think of that might have any effect would be that I am using a new version of Eclipse which might cause it to mistake the Encoding, but I have tried checking all the common encoding types and nothing provides the HTML plaintext.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? It's not a disaster if I can't get this right but I would like to know for the future in case I run into the same problem again.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Util {
    private static final String BEFORE = "<button class=btn TYPE=BUTTON onClick=\"self.location='", AFTER = "'\">Next &gt;</button>", SITE = "fanfiction.net";

    public static String readSite(String path) throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL(path);
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String line;
        try{
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            line = in.readLine();
            if(line == null){
                return null;
            }
            builder.append(line);
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append('\n' + line);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } finally{
            if(in != null){
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static String updatePathToEnd(String path) throws Exception{
        outer: while(nextExists(path)){
            String data = readSite(path);
            if(path.contains(SITE)){
                String link = path.substring(0, path.indexOf(SITE) + SITE.length()) + data.substring(data.indexOf(BEFORE) + BEFORE.length(), data.indexOf(AFTER));
                if(readSite(link) != null) {
                    path = link;
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    public static boolean nextExists(String path) throws Exception{
        String text = readSite(path);
        if(path.contains(SITE)){
            return text==null ? false : text.contains(AFTER);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried in bluej and works perfect, it seems that the problem is in Eciplse
Regards

Comment: Thank you. I will try to look through Eclipse for encoding settings then. Can also try exporting the program and see if it works when run outside of Eclipse (like the old one does)